Where did Jesus Christ claim to be God?
I need help on trying to find scriptures in all the four gospels where Jesus claims to be God!

I understand why this question was closed but am still disappointed it was.  I would argue that there were numerous times Jesus claimed to be god such as several unpredicated "I AM" statements, (eg, John 8:23, 24, 28, 58, 59, 18:4-8, etc) and His confession before the High Priest in Mark 14:61-64.  There are many more.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics forum, malachiMDJ. What you're asking here is actually more in the domain of "Christian apologetics" in defense of our precious faith. But let me provide some observations for you.

People arguing against the deity of Christ often ask this question, which is actually very silly. Many people today and in the past have claimed they were God, which is usually the sign of mental illness.

People who argue with you often use the tactic of giving you "homework assignments" requiring large commitments of your time, while they themselves won't even lift a finger. Then when you come back with a scholarly paper that took you hours and days to write, they simply brush it off claiming that it wasn't convincing despite their not having even read it.

Jesus himself was confronted by religious leaders in his generation. Here's how he handled it:



And the Pharisees and Sadducees came, and to test him they asked him
to show them a sign from heaven . . . [Jesus told them] "An evil and
adulterous generation seeks for a sign, but no sign will be given to
it except the sign of Jonah.” So he left them and departed. - Matthew
16:1, 4 ESV

Just as Jonah spent three days and three nights in the heart of the abyss and was resurrected, so Jesus spent three days and three nights in the grave and was resurrected to life, which was witnessed by hundreds of people in many places over 40 days.

God himself identified Jesus in front of many witnesses:


. . . and behold, a voice from heaven said, “This is my beloved Son,
with whom I am well pleased.” - Matthew 3:17 ESV


. . . He was still speaking when, behold, a bright cloud overshadowed
them, and a voice from the cloud said, “This is my beloved Son, with
whom I am well pleased; listen to him.” - Matthew 17:5 ESV

Where does it say that Allah spoke from heaven in front of many witnesses saying, "This is Muhammed, my prophet, listen to him." in the Quran?

Jesus came as the Messiah, the Lamb of God, to take away the sin of the world. He did not come and order people to worship him as God.

Jesus fulfilled a large number of prophecies concerning the Messiah.

Jesus performed many miracles in front of massive crowds, demonstrating that he was truly sent from God.

Matthew 16, Mark 8, Luke 9, and John 10 all attest to the identity of Jesus. And also consider



Jesus said to him, “Have I been with you so long, and you still do not
know me, Philip? Whoever has seen me has seen the Father. How can you
say, ‘Show us the Father’? - John 14:9 ESV


There are many other testimonies, even from his enemies who crucified Jesus on the charge of blasphemy because he claimed equality with God.

You might simply suggest to your tormentors that even if you come up with all the verses in the Bible demonstrating that Jesus was indeed the Son of God and the exact representation of God that they would still not believe.

Long ago, at many times and in many ways, God spoke to our fathers by
the prophets, but in these last days he has spoken to us by his Son,
whom he appointed the heir of all things, through whom also he created
the world. He is the radiance of the glory of God and the exact
imprint of his nature, and he upholds the universe by the word of his
power. After making purification for sins, he sat down at the right
hand of the Majesty on high, having become as much superior to
angels as the name he has inherited is more excellent than theirs. -
Hebrews 1:1-4 ESV


He [Jesus] is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of all
creation. For by him all things were created, in heaven and on earth,
visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or
authorities—all things were created through him and for him. And he is
before all things, and in him all things hold together. And he is the
head of the body, the church. He is the beginning, the firstborn from
the dead, that in everything he might be preeminent. For in him all
the fullness of God was pleased to dwell, and through him to reconcile
to himself all things, whether on earth or in heaven, making peace by
the blood of his cross. Colossians 1:15-20 ESV

Suggest to them that if they were truly sincere about their question, they should devote three days in prayer asking God to reveal the truth to them! Three days is a trivial amount of time in view of an eternity in heaven or hell is at stake!
I hope this helps.

Thank you very much! Amen

You're very welcome, @malachiMDJ! God bless you and don't worry about any down votes on this forum! I certainly don't. :-)
